# fmincon - outcomes not close to original parameters

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to resolve a problem using the MATLAB fmincon function.  I have an equation shown below, for which I have generated testing data using some timepoints.  I would like to estimate the parameters x(1), x(2), and x(3) by using optimization, based on the testing data generated.  The parameters currently estimated using fmincon are not close to the initial parameters I used to generate the data. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Testing data; 
    Timepoints = [10:10:300, 500, 700, 1000];
    x = [0.1, 0.5, 0.3]; % parameters of interest 
    Data = x(1)*sin(x(2).*Timepoints)+log(x(3).*Timepoints); % Generating data using a testing equation

```
% Parameters used to run the fmincon
x0 = [0, 0.1, 0.1]; % initial guess
lb = zeros(1, length(x0)); % lower bound of parameters
ub = ones(1, length(x0)); % upper bound of parameters

[x, fval, exitflag, output] = fmincon(@modelA1, x0, [], [], [], [], lb, ub, [], options, Timepoints, Data); 


function fvalues = modelA(x, Timepoints, fvals) 
Fvalues = zeros(1, length(Timepoints)); 
PreFvalues = zeros(1, length(Timepoints)); 

for Temp = 1:length(Timepoints)
tempY = x0(1)*sin(x0(2).*Timepoints(Temp))+log(x0(3).*Timepoints(Temp));
PreFvalues(Temp) = (fvals(Temp)-tempY)^2; 
end 
fvalues=sqrt(sum(PreFvalues));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When providing a code example, at least make sure that it works, and include the code that defines the test data.

After suitable modification to make it work, the following code shows that the solution generated by your code is pretty good.  You have a quite non-linear function so it's not surprising that the solution is a local minima rather than a global minima (i.e. the original solution).  You'll get slightly different results depending on the initial condition (i.e. x0).

For this problem I'd also suggest using `lsqcurvefit` rather than `fmincon`.  An example of this is also in the code.

```
function test

Timepoints = [10:10:300, 500, 700, 1000]; x = [0.1, 0.5, 0.3]; 
Data = x(1)*sin(x(2).*Timepoints)+log(x(3).*Timepoints);

options = optimoptions('fmincon');

% Parameters used to run the fmincon
x0 = [0, 0.1, 0.1]; % initial guess
lb = zeros(1, length(x0)); % lower bound of parameters
ub = ones(1, length(x0)); % upper bound of parameters

[x, fval, exitflag, output] = fmincon(@modelA, x0, [], [], [], [], lb, ub, [], options, Timepoints, Data); 

% Using lsqcurvefit
F = @(x,xData)x(1)*sin(x(2).*xData)+log(x(3).*xData);
x = lsqcurvefit(F,x0,Timepoints,Data,lb,ub);

plot(...
    Timepoints,Data,...
    Timepoints,x(1)*sin(x(2).*Timepoints)+log(x(3).*Timepoints),...
    Timepoints,F(x,Timepoints));
legend({'Original','fmincon','lsqcurvefit'});

function fvalues = modelA(x, Timepoints, fvals) 

tempY = x(1)*sin(x(2)*Timepoints)+log(x(3)*Timepoints);
PreFvalues = (fvals-tempY).^2; 

fvalues=sum(PreFvalues);
```

Answer (score 0):

When providing a code example, at least make sure that it works, and include the code that defines the test data.

After suitable modification to make it work, the following code shows that the solution generated by your code is pretty good.  You have a quite non-linear function so it's not surprising that the solution is a local minima rather than a global minima (i.e. the original solution).  You'll get slightly different results depending on the initial condition (i.e. x0).

For this problem I'd also suggest using `lsqcurvefit` rather than `fmincon`.  An example of this is also in the code.

```
function test

Timepoints = [10:10:300, 500, 700, 1000]; x = [0.1, 0.5, 0.3]; 
Data = x(1)*sin(x(2).*Timepoints)+log(x(3).*Timepoints);

options = optimoptions('fmincon');

% Parameters used to run the fmincon
x0 = [0, 0.1, 0.1]; % initial guess
lb = zeros(1, length(x0)); % lower bound of parameters
ub = ones(1, length(x0)); % upper bound of parameters

[x, fval, exitflag, output] = fmincon(@modelA, x0, [], [], [], [], lb, ub, [], options, Timepoints, Data); 

% Using lsqcurvefit
F = @(x,xData)x(1)*sin(x(2)*xData)+log(x(3)*xData);
x = lsqcurvefit(F,x0,Timepoints,Data,lb,ub);

plot(...
    Timepoints,Data,...
    Timepoints,x(1)*sin(x(2).*Timepoints)+log(x(3).*Timepoints),...
    Timepoints,F(x,Timepoints));
legend({'Original','fmincon','lsqcurvefit'});

function fvalues = modelA(x, Timepoints, fvals) 

tempY = x(1)*sin(x(2)*Timepoints)+log(x(3)*Timepoints);
PreFvalues = (fvals-tempY).^2; 

fvalues=sum(PreFvalues);
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  When I ran the script, I got x = [0.0131, 0.9772, 0.2976] for fmincon and x=[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.2973] for lsqcurvefit.  I am wondering whether that's what you got too.